# GPG hangs on MacOS

Tags: macos, gpg

When trying to access secret keys, my GPG hangs. The existing solutions suggested killing `gpg-agent`, but that didn't help for me. I tried debug logging (see below), but couldn't make anything out of it.

My OS is MacOS Sonoma, and I'm running gpg 2.4.3 from Homebrew.

```shellsession
$ pkill -9 gpg-agent

~
$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.4.3
libgcrypt 1.10.2
Copyright (C) 2023 g10 Code GmbH
License GNU GPL-3.0-or-later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: /Users/mporkola/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2

~
$ gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format=long --debug-level guru
gpg: enabled debug flags: packet mpi crypto filter iobuf memory cache memstat trust hashing ipc clock lookup extprog
gpg: enabled compatibility flags:
gpg: DBG: [no clock] start
gpg: using pgp trust model
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this out of the box with the same versions on macOS. Do you have a GnuPG key in your setup?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I encountered this issue randomly after my macOS install crashed overnight 2 days ago. I am running macOS Sonoma 14.2.1. I really have no idea what happened, and I encountered this issue because my Emacs was hanging was navigating files/directories with `find-file`.

The command that was freezing my Emacs seemed to be:

```bash
/usr/local/bin/gpg --with-colons --no-greeting --batch --with-fingerprint --with-fingerprint --fixed-list-mode --list-keys "Frederick"
```

### Solution

#### An apparent solution (downgrading gpg)

On this seemingly unrelated issue on the Doom Emacs repo, a Arch Linux user reported a hang when saving `gpg` files. Their solution was to install `gnupg@2.2`, since there seemed to be a problem with the latest `2.4.3` build.
[[doomemacs/doomemacs] Can't save epa encrypted org .gpg file #7589](https://github.com/doomemacs/doomemacs/issues/7589)

Given that their solution was to downgrade to `gnupg@2.2`, I thought I'd try the same. Running the following commands seemed to *just work*:

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies gnupg; # uninstall gpg
brew install gnupg@2.2; # install gpg@2.2
brew link gnupg@2.2; # link the new version of gpg to /usr/local/bin
```

After running those commands everything appeared to **just work**. The above command would no longer hang.

#### Getting `gpg v2.4.3` to work

Before I went through this whole process of installing the working version of `gpupg@2.2`, when I ran the hanging command the first time, it failed on acquiring a lock on `~/.gnupg`. Looking at Activity Monitor I saw there was a TON of `gpg` processes running. A quick `killall gpg` killed the processes.

I deleted the lock file at `~/.gnupg/gnupg_spawn_keyboxd_sentinel.lock`. Didn't work. This is about when I proceeded to install `gpupg@2.2`.

**BUT** later I saw that there was *another* lock file. Namely, `~/.gnupg/public-keys.d/pubring.db.lock`. I did not delete this lock file the first time.

So. Let's reinstall the latest `gnupg`... Before I did this, I did not delete that lock file.

- Commands:

  ```bash
  brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies gnupg@2.2;
  brew install gnupg;
  ```
- Verify `gpg` is stuck:

  ```bash
  /usr/local/bin/gpg --with-colons --no-greeting --batch --with-fingerprint --with-fingerprint --fixed-list-mode --list-keys "Frederick"
  ```

  Great!(?) It's still stuck.

If we delete the lock files now at `~/.gnupg/gnupg_spawn_keyboxd_sentinel.lock` and `~/.gnupg/public-keys.d/pubring.db.lock`, the above command seems to work!

### Some More Questions

- Regarding @Kusalananda comment above, I do not know if I had a GnuPG key in my setup. Maybe I did? But for the `gnupg@2.2` and `gnupg` packages (once I got them working) I got the message:

  ```
  gpg: error reading key: No public key
  ```

  Okay... interesting.
- What caused this though?

  - That is a GOOD question. My Emacs was working fine, and then I had that power-off event, and then it did not work any longer (due to the `gpg` hang).
  - `gnupg` was updated to `2.4.3` around 9 months ago at the time of writing. So it wasn't an upgrade issue I think. Given that this occurred after a power-off event, deals with that db `.lock` file, and that `gnupg@2.2` did not have this problem when installed, I would wager that perhaps there was something introduced that respected that db `.lock` file. Just a guess...
- From the comment above about missing a key, and the fact that I'm getting those message, perhaps that is related. I'm not sure if I had keys and they got corrupted or what. Either way, this appeared to not have been an issue (in terms of command freezing) in `gnupg@2.2`.

I originally posted about my issue on a different Issue in the Doom Emacs Github Issue Tracker. The user they experienced a power-off event and could no longer open files. I'm wondering if perhaps the power-off events are related to the issues we're having with `gpg`. They did not report any issues with `gpg`, but it seems like they didn't post much debug info.

[[doomemacs/doomemacs] Fresh install in MacOS Ventura freezes when any file is opened #7289](https://github.com/doomemacs/doomemacs/issues/7289#issuecomment-1892591537)